# Ethernet/ip SImulator sofwares

Tags: iot

I would like to excersize ethernet/ip protocol communication in linux.
I found that there are some free scanner simulator tools like do-more scanner simulator and ethernet/ip explorer which could be installed in windows.
I want to read the scanner simulator data from a linux machine. Are there any adaptor programs which work for linux?

Answer (score 1):

CIPster is a C++ library for implementing Ethernet/IP adapters. It is hosted here: https://github.com/liftoff-sr/CIPster

They have an example Adapter you may be able to use here: https://github.com/liftoff-sr/CIPster/blob/master/examples/POSIX/sample_application/sampleapplication.cc